# Others pages like anyorigin.com

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am facing a strange issue while trying to open pages inside my page.

It worked fine during a couple of weeks with the pages I use to open but not anymore. It works with others like http:www.terra.es (for example) but not with mines.

I am trying to open this webpage and similars: 
    http://portal.ayto-santander.es/santander_inet/Ficha?itemId=7279236

I tried with anyorigin.com and with whateverorigin.org In both it worked in past but not anymore.

Any idea about how to solve this issue? It is a little bit strange because I am almost sure the domain has not change anything in this configuration.

This is my code for showing the webpage inside my webpage:

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url='+parameters['page']+'&callback=?', function(data){
                        //console.log(data.contents);
                        if(data.contents.indexOf('404 Not Found') >= 0 || data.contents.indexOf('alarm') >= 0){
    $('#divPage').html("Not valid link");
}
else{
    $('#divPage').html(data.contents);
}
                    });
```

Why am I having trouble connecting to anyorigin.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep the following note in mind from the anyorigin.com homepage:

> Notice: You need to pay for this service   if you intend to use it.
>   Not doing so with excessive use may result in blocking of your app.

Now, there could be two reasons you cannot do this anymore:

1. Anyorgin blocked this url because payment is required
2. The web admin for the website you are fetching (e.g.  http://portal.ayto-santander.es) blocked AnyOrigin from accessing its site/server

Comment: Um. I will ask to the webadmin of the second point. About the first one, maybe it is because of that, I don't know, but I just use it 3 or 4 times to test it before now. I will check other solutions cos I really need it. Thank you.

Comment: I solved using iframes. It works fine now. Since anyother answer were writen. I will set yours as correct because it helped me and what you say is true.